# Why is the scientist kidnapped and brainwashed?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-ipcress-file

In *The Ipcress File*, Harry Palmer is tasked with finding and recovering Radcliffe, a British scientist who is suspected to have been kidnapped by a man named Grantby.  Palmer does recover the scientist, but it turns out that he has been brainwashed and is unable to recollect anything about his work.

Whilst watching the film recently, it occurred to me that the motive for kidnapping and brainwashing the scientist was not explained. Grantby does obtain a ransom from the British Government by returning the scientist to them. However, if he was motivated purely by financial gain, why go to the trouble of brainwashing him?

The film is set in the 1960s, at the height of the Cold War, so it's possible that Grantby is collaborating with the Russians to undermine British scientific research. Even if this is true, wouldn't it be easier to just kill the scientist, rather than go to the trouble of brainwashing him?

I haven't read the Len Deighton novel that the film was based on.  Perhaps the book provides more explanation of Grantby's motives, which was lost when adapting it for the film? Does anyone know?